# ffmpeg stream loop video forward and in reverse

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to take an input video and horizontally concatenate it with itself in reverse (play it forwards then backwards) using a filter_complex. So far I have split it over 3 commands, reversing, concatenating, and streaming, but I want to do it in one command. The following streams a video twice but I don't know how to reverse the second video. How does one reverse the second copy of the video without changing the first one?

```sh
ffmpeg -re -stream_loop -1 -i self_recording.mkv -filter_complex \
    "[0:v]split=2[r1][r2];[0:v][r1][0:v][r2] concat=n=4:v=1[v]" \
    -map "[v]" -f v4l2 /dev/video2
```

Comment: You'll need to encode the video once where a forward play is joined with reverse play. Then stream_loop that resulting file.

Comment: Is there a way to do that in ffmpeg without waiting until the video is fully reversed and concatenated before it starts streaming? E.g. if there's a 2 minute video that needs to be streamed, can the stream start immediately without making temporary files? My inefficient way of streaming forwards and backwards can be found here on lines 112, 116, and finally 130, and I want to replace it with something more efficient. https://github.com/intermezzio/webcam-video-effects/blob/008cf1e9ca1bbd05e3b25a64fd77c1a484f43da9/video_looper_complete.sh#L112

Comment: No. In this case, the input has to be ready before streaming command starts. But the file can be prepped in one step with watermarking.

Comment: What would be the command to prep the input in one command via watermarking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Video Prep:

```
ffmpeg -i "$video" -i "$watermark" \
       -filter_complex "[0]split=2[fr][rv];[rv]reverse[rv]; \
                        [fr][rv]concat=n=2:v=1:a=0,$memestr,$rotatestr[jt]; \
                        [1][jt]scale2ref[i][m];[m][i]overlay=format=auto,format=yuv420p[v]" \
       -map "[v]" -g 30 stream.mp4
```

Stream:

```
ffmpeg -stream_loop -1 -re -i "stream.mp4" -c copy -f v4l2 "/dev/video$output"
```